# Implementing LeNet in keras. How can I only combine some feature maps in a convolution layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Im currently trying to implement LeNet from its original paper in keras. In there the architecture is defined as follows

[image: Lenet architecure]

The authors also describe, that in convolution layer C3, not all filters are applied to all of the feature maps of the previous layer. They also provide this table to define, which feature maps are combined for use with what filter. It seems that every implementation I have found does not do this.

[image]

So my questions are

- How can I add this sort of behaviour?
- Also why does every implementation of LeNet I have found seem to ignore this part?

Here is my current code without the selective application of filters.

```
model = keras.Sequential()

#C1
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32,32,1)))
#S2    
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D())
#C3
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D())

model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.add(layers.Dense(units=120, activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dense(units=84, activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dense(units=10, activation = 'softmax'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fairly easy take certain slices of the tensor, produced by a NN layer, by using functional API.

Namely, let `conv_1=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(parameters)` be the layer from which you want to extract certain feature maps. Correspondingly, in the definition of the model you would have

```
    features = conv_1(previous_features)
```

If you want to get, say, feature maps from channels 3,4, and 5, you can use `tf.slice` or use pythonic/numpy indexes (which are supported by TF):

```
    # assuming dimensions are (batch_size, height, width, channels)
    feature_maps = features[:,:,:,3:6]
```

To take arbitrary channels, you may first need to make a list out of your `features` by unstacking `features` along channel axis by using `tf.unstack`:

```
    features_list = tf.unstack(feature_maps, axis=-1)
```

This produces a list of tensors, each of which is a particular feature map. Then you can combine them together into a new tensor by using `tf.satck`:

```
    # let a1, ..., an are indexes of the channels you need.
    particular_features = tf.stack( [features_list[a1], ... , features_list[an] ], axis=-1 )
```

You can use thus obtained feature maps further in the network by passing them as arguments to further layers. This should do the work.

I am unfamiliar with any realizations of LeNet models, so I cannot comment on this.